# Is there a Pi 3 Model B OEM version for Commercial Use?

Tags: commercial-use

I would like to purchase 500-1000 Raspberry Pi 3 Model B OEM units for commercial use.

How can I purchase the OEM version of the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B?

Comment: What do you mean by OEM. Aren't they all OEM. It is not like an arduino with multiple clones.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. It is my understanding that you can use the Raspberry Pi in commercial products (see [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/34036/19949)). If you cannot purchase your desired number of units through the available vendors you might need to address the Raspberry Pi Foundation directly.

Comment: @Ghanima thanks for your response. I found the OEM option from [your link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34035/can-i-use-raspberry-pi-in-commercial-production/34036#34036). As I understand OEM is special production for customer.

Answer (score 5):

The Raspberry Pi is made by a number of different partner companies. It is not actually manufactured by the Raspberry Pi Foundation itself.

The manufacture of Raspberry Pi's as far as I am aware is by Element14/Premier Farnell. Originally they were made in China but are now produced in the UK, which is fitting, given the Foundation is a British organisation. You can read more about that [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/made-in-the-uk/).

In terms of a Pi made for commercial use element 14 have an exclusive [Raspberry Pi customization area](https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-76955/l/raspberry-pi-customization-service). This allows companies to order customized Pi's in bulk orders.

You might also be interested in the [Compute Module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-compute-module-new-product/), which fits in a DDR2 SODIMM connector. This is aimed at people looking to produce custom PCBs.

The main thing to note is wherever you buy, say a Pi 3 Model B from. (Assuming its a reputable source). It will have been made to the same specifications as the rest of the Pi 3 Model B's. There is not a specific enterprise model, like there is for other computer hardware such as RAM and hard drives.