# Can we manufacture a product using same board design as Raspberry Pi?

Tags: hardware, design, commercial-use

If we program an app on Raspberry Pi, can we duplicate the Raspberry Pi hardware design, manufacture our own boards, and sell them as our product without paying license or royalty for the hardware design?

Comment: `yes you can` .....  are you really going to believe a stranger on the internet? contact the RPi manufacturer about any licensing questions

Comment: Read [this thread first](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34035/can-i-use-raspberry-pi-in-commercial-production); if you still have questions, please let us know.

Answer (score 2):

The hardware design is not "open source".  Even if you acquire a license to duplicate the hardware you might not be able to buy any Broadcom SoCs (minimum order quantities in the tens of thousands).